# Check if a file exists in a directory or request another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there any .htaccess rule that checks if requested file does not exist in "mydir" and get `index.php?get=mydir`

I tried this but not working:

```
RewriteCond mydir/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache, I would suggest using this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_actions.html

This may not be the best approach but it works for me.

Basically you will setup a script that Apache will send all requests through.

```
# Files of a particular file extension
AddHandler handler .html
Action handler /handler.php
```

Each time a html file is requested, Apache will run handler.php.

Inside `handler.php`, you can use `$_SERVER` to determine the requested file, check if it exists and include it if it does exits. If it doesn't exist, do whatever you need to do.

Comment: thans Kyle this is usefull for my other problems :D

Comment: you're welcome. It may be possible to just create a custom 404 error document that does what you need but I haven't tried this. `ErrorDocument 404 /whatever_you_need_to_show`

Answer (score 1):

To serve a page if it exists else serve other one, add the following to your .htaccess file,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# serve file if exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/index.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cache/index.html [L,QSA]

# else serve other file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/index.html !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Do not forget that for this to work you should have **AllowOverride All** in your vhosts file.